# Is the are form to compact this statements, need a for loop?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am new in the pandas dataFrames and I have this repetitive code, how can I improve that?

```
# Import the libraries
from random import random
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Make different arrays of random values
cells_1 = pd.DataFrame({"mRNA Transcripts": np.random.randint(0, 10, 12000)})
cells_2 = pd.DataFrame({"mRNA Transcripts": np.random.randint(30, 40, 12000)})
cells_3 = pd.DataFrame({"mRNA Transcripts": np.random.randint(11, 14, 24000)})
cells_4 = pd.DataFrame({"mRNA Transcripts": np.random.randint(26, 29, 24000)})
cells_5 = pd.DataFrame({"mRNA Transcripts": np.random.randint(15, 25, 168000)})

# Add in the previous DataFrames to make one only
cells_6 = cells_1.append(cells_2)
cells_7 = cells_6.append(cells_3)
cells_8 = cells_7.append(cells_4)
cells = cells_8.append(cells_5)

cells
```

I want to create a normal fit with only unique dataframe, here's the reason why I start with lesser values than in the mean of the future graphic.

Result:

```
mRNA Transcripts
    0   4
    1   9
    2   0
    3   4
    4   4
    ... ...
    167995  16
    167996  22
    167997  20
    167998  17
    167999  24
    240000 rows × 1 columns
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you seemingly have consecutive, non-overlapping integer ranges, you can define the bins in advance as a list  and then concatenate the random numpy arrays for the dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import default_rng
rng = default_rng()

#define the bins 1-10, 11-14, 15-25, ....
#the right value is always excluded, so the last one must be +1
bins = [0, 11, 15, 26, 30, 41]
#define how many random elements you want to draw for each bin
#0-10: 2, 11-14: 4,....
bin_elem = [2, 4, 3, 4, 5]

cells = pd.DataFrame({"mRNA Transcripts": 
                  np.concatenate([rng.integers(start, stop-1, num) 
                  for start, stop, num in zip(bins[:-1], bins[1:], bin_elem)])})

print(cells)
```

This uses the new [numpy random generator](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/random/index.html#random-quick-start).